# Ant Design Dynamic Data does not binds to Select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am using react for a school project. The dynamic data does not binds to Options from Ant Design, react js. The result is an empty option list. In actual the data comes from an external API. For testing purpose I assigned the data the state variable. The data comes in 2D array, so I am mapping through the data twice.

Result is:

[image]

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

const Complete = () => {
    const [list, setPersons] = useState([
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                personName: "Owan",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                personName: "More",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                personName: "Jaila",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                personName: "Eerov",
            },
        ],
        [
            {
                id: 5,
                personName: "Rell",
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                personName: "Juko",
            }
        ]
    ]);


    

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(list);
    }, []);

    return (
        <Select
            showSearch
            style={{ width: 200 }}
            placeholder="Select a person"
            optionFilterProp="children"
            
            filterOption={(input, option) =>
                option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }
        >
            {list.map((l) => {

                l.map((person) => {
                    console.log(person);
                    <Option value={person.id}>
                        {person.personName}
                    </Option>;
                });
            })}
        </Select>
    );
};

export default Complete;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

const Complete = () => {
  const [list, setPersons] = useState([
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        personName: "Owan"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        personName: "More"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        personName: "Jaila"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        personName: "Eerov"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 5,
        personName: "Rell"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        personName: "Juko"
      }
    ]
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(list);
  }, [list]);

  return (
    <Select
      showSearch
      style={{ width: 200 }}
      placeholder="Select a person"
      optionFilterProp="children"
      filterOption={(input, option) =>
        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      }
    >
      {list.map((l) => (
        <>
          {l.map((person) => (
            <Option value={person.id}>{person.personName}</Option>
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};

export default Complete;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, May I know, What you have changed, other than adding "list" in useEffect. I just added that in my code, it does not work. Actually, I tried that before.

Comment: Check on this sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/lively-river-0t7fi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

user return parenthesis () in map method not {} curly parenthesis

Comment: Btw, I see you have used, <>
        </> after {list.map((l) => (..... Why is it so?

Comment: Happy to help you!

Comment: And It works, Thanks. Can you please clear my doubt

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html 
Read this and don't forget to upvote thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to update small one using **ES6 feature** here the script to combine **2 dimensional array to single array**

```
{[].concat(...list).map((l) => <Option value={l.id}>{l.personName}</Option>)}
```

**Here the full script:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

const Complete = () => {
    const [list, setPersons] = useState([
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                personName: "Owan",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                personName: "More",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                personName: "Jaila",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                personName: "Eerov",
            },
        ],
        [
            {
                id: 5,
                personName: "Rell",
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                personName: "Juko",
            }
        ]
    ]);


    

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(list);
    }, []);

    return (
        <Select
            showSearch
            style={{ width: 200 }}
            placeholder="Select a person"
            optionFilterProp="children"
            
            filterOption={(input, option) =>
                option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }
        >
            {[].concat(...list).map((l) => <Option value={l.id}>{l.personName}</Option>)}
        </Select>
    );
};

export default Complete;
```

visit live example [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-dropdown-antd-4-17-2-forked-pd16b?file=/index.js)